# Playing a sound on button click with Android

Tags: java, android, button, android-mediaplayer

I know a thousand different versions of this question have been asked, and I've looked through them and tried the suggestions but none have worked. I'm trying to play a sound when a button is clicked while also showing new text on the screen. I get the text to toggle when I press the button, but the sound never plays. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
TextView text;
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("myaudio.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            toggleString(v);
        }
    });
}

public void toggleString(View v) {
    if(text.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.nothing)))
        text.setText(R.string.answer);
    else
        text.setText(R.string.nothing);
}
```

This is my activity xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/nothing"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/question" 
    />
```

If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is what I saw in the console after I tried the second suggestion (is this the print stack? I'm sorry, I don't know what that is)

```
   [2014-02-08 15:17:14 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:763)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)

[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8602 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8603 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8604 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8605 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8606 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8607 for debugger
[2014-02-08 15:19:44 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8608 for debugger
```

Comment: Does an error occur in the catch? Post the printStackTrace you receive when you tried to play the sound.

Comment: I added what I saw to the end of the post

Comment: That is because the create is failing. It is never getting to the prepared state. You are still in the initial state when trying to play. I was asking what the print stack was of your first try.

Comment: I don't know what the print stack but I hope what I just edited is it. I think it is.

Comment: The first suggestion is correct. If it is not working your myaudio.mp3 maybe in the wrong place. Or your volume on your device is turned all the way down. Look at the first try catch in the first suggestion. you see e1.printStackTrace(); that is allowing your program not to crash but outputting the error in log Cat, if there is an error. It should be in red I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the data source and prepare the media player one time.

Try this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd("myaudio.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        try {     
            mp.start();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting the error that I added to the end of my original post.

Comment: Are you using the emulator ?

Comment: I was but then I started using my phone (Galaxy S4)

Answer (score 1):

```
#import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mySound;
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.blop);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mySound.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.blop);
            /* Optional */ // mySound.start();
        }
        toggleString(v);
    }
});
}
```

Instead of Assets, try saving your sound file in raw folder, and call MediaPlayer.create within your activity. In example above, sound file in raw folder is named blop.

Comment: I actually had something like this at first because I put the mp3 file in a raw folder, but it still wouldn't working. And with this the app won't open at all...